# Optional enum initializer not working with where clause

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm having trouble composing a `guard` with a `where` clause and want to verify whether I'm doing this correctly or if the compiler is being buggy.

I have this enum:

```
enum Command: String {
    case Init
    case Update
}
```

And then this guard statement

```
let cmdStr = "Init"

guard let command = Command(rawValue: cmdStr) where command != nil else {
    print("invalid command: \(cmdStr)") // Error: Value of type Command can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed
    return nil
}
```

The error I get is strange, because the rawValue initializer is an optional initializer. Introspecting `command` shows that it is type `Command` though, even though the initializer results in an optional.

However, if I do this outside the guard statement first and rewrite like this:

```
let cmdStr = "Init"
let cmd = Command(rawValue: cmdStr)

guard cmd != nil else {
    print("invalid command: \(cmdStr)")
    return nil
}
```

It works and introspection of `cmd` shows the expected type of `Command?`

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or is this a compiler bug I should be submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read Apple Documentation about guard statement:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525

In your case there should be

```
let cmdStr = "Init"

guard let command = Command(rawValue: cmdStr) else {
    print("invalid command: \(cmdStr)") // Error: Value of type Command can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes a lot of sense. There's no need for the where statement because guard is already checking whether it's nil. Thanks.